# Codeception: Acceptance Testing not working

Tags: codeception, php-7, acceptance-testing, ubuntu-16.04

[image: Codeception\Exception\TestParseException]

I am getting the above exception (Image) when I try to run the acceptance test in `codeception`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change folder permission on /var/www/Wordpress... with chmod or chown

Comment: changing permission does not help. I tried running it in home directory and face the same issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: add sudo/ su to your command. Do it as root

Comment: No ! that doesnt solve it either !

Comment: Can't help you if I have no more informations

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help . It was my mistake . I did not configure the acceptance.suite.yml file properly. Now it is working . Sorry for the vagueness of question.